# What does it mean by "my days-of-the-week underwear only go to Thursday" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs, ellipsis

> Emily: Lorelai? I'm going shopping this afternoon. I thought I'd pick up a few things for Rory.
>
> Lor: I already took care of all that, mom. I got her two skirts and a bunch of tops.
>
> Emily: But there are five days in a school week.
>
> Lor: Really? Because *my days-of-the-week underwear only **go to** Thursday.*
>
> Emily: Is that a joke?
>
> Lor: Two skirts are fine, mom.

This conversation is from the [Gilmore Girls](https://everipedia.org/wiki/lang_en/Gilmore_Girls) TV series. Lorelai is Rory’s mother.

I googled "days of the week underwear" and found out that they are a set of underwear with days of the week written on them.

But what's the meaning of "go to" in this context? 
I don't understand what this sentence as a whole means.

Comment: don't understand the down vote. As a non-English speaker the meaning of "go to thursday" wasn't easy to grasp even after googling online especially because "go" has so many meanings.

Comment: And because _to_ has many usages too. :) Anyway, to protect your questions from negative feedback (down votes, close votes, etc), try to provide some research, even if it seems pointless.

Comment: Not sure saying "even if it seems pointless" is very good advice, looking up **go to** in a dictionary and posting a link IN the question, would have shown that the answer is not at all "obvious": https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-to_1

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, that was my point. It may seem sufficient to simply say "I didn't find anything useful", but some aren't convinced by that (e.g. the close/down voters). So (any) OP can help convince those voters by providing that research, that link the OP thinks wasn't not useful. Of course, you can't convince everyone. :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*Go from [something] to [something else]* can describe or define a sequence from the first something to the other something. In other words, *from* and *to* are being used in an ordinary way to indicate a starting point and an ending point.

> - It goes from A to D. → A B C D
> - ... goes from 1 to 3. → 1 2 3
> - [These go to 11.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOO5S4vxi0o) → 1 2 3... 10 11

It's understood that the starting point is Monday, since that's when the school week starts. Hence

> Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday

---

Days-of-the-week underwear are underwear with the days of the week printed on it, one day per pair. When Lorelai says

> Really? Because my days-of-the-week underwear only go to Thursday.

she's implying that she doesn't know there are five days in the school week because she only has four days-of-the-week underwear (Monday through Thursday). As others have stated, this is sarcasm. We can infer that the intention is something like

> I know there are five days in a school week. I don't need to be reminded.

Answer (score 31):

It is possible to buy [underwear with a day printed](https://www.google.com/search?q=day%20of%20the%20week%20underwear&sxsrf=ACYBGNRWKuqvB_HvQHeyJL7jRkdU2jOGqg:1569135540856&source=lnms&tbm=shop&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTlJG07ePkAhUKQRUIHYzoBnAQ_AUIEigB&biw=1366&bih=670) on it as a joke or as a gentle reminder to a child (or adult) to change their pants each day.

But I think Lorelai is being very sarcastic here. Emily implies that only two skirts are not enough, and Rory should be wearing a fresh skirt each day. Lorelai sarcastically says "I didn't know that there are five school days, because my kids pants go to Thursday" ("go to Thursday" means she has Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thrusday, but not Friday) This means (without sarcasm) "I know that there are five school days. Everybody knows that. I don't need to look at my pants to find out which day it is."

The use of sarcasm is very common when teens talk to their parents.

Comment: thanks, I understood the sarcasm here. But I'm still not quite sure about the "go to" part. So what she means by (not the implied meaning) "underwear go to thursday" is that *she only **has** four underwear*, each of which has Monday to Thursday printed on them?

Comment: I think the whole phrase is sarcastic.  Lorelei doesn't actually have any day-of-the-week pants. However, she claims that she only has four pairs: Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu but not Fri.  Since it is not to be taken seriously, I don't think we can draw any more implications

Comment: there is utterly no connection to underwear with literally words printed on them. It's completely commonplace tos peak about your "days of the week underwear" simply meaning "you have a fresh pair for each day of the week."  It's that simple.

Comment: @Fattie I don't agree. If I hear people referring to "days-of-the-week underwear" I would assume it has the days printed on it. It is a fairly common product. I suppose someone could have a system "red = monday" etc but I wouldn't assume that.

Comment: Really, the question is just "what does 'go to' mean in this context".  And it simply means "runs through ..", "I have up to...".

Comment: Lorelai is not a teen. She is Rory’s mother.

Comment: Meanwhile, Irish me is just being very confused that Rory is apparently a girl's name. Americans are strange.

Comment: @TRiG, in this case, Rory is short for Lorelai. It is of course still strange if one is acquainted with the male first name.

Comment: @CarstenS Lorelei and Emily have a stunted relationship, which never really matured beyond the mother-teenager stage.

Comment: @Barmar, good point.

Comment: @TRiG To be fair, I fully expect that was deliberate on the writers' part.  It's not uncommon among American TV shows (particularly in the late 90s/early 00s,) to give at least one main character an unusual name in order to make them stand out.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like a sexual innuendo. The surrounding context makes the situation sound like a late teen female discussing a younger sibling with her mum. Given that Lorelai is shopping for clothes for her younger sibling, it is safe to assume she is either legally an adult or almost so.

Lorelai's day of the week pants only go to Thursday. The literal meaning is in Em's answer. But the hidden implication is that Lorelai does not wear pants on a Friday.

This is potentially an off colour joke, given mum's reaction. The same phrase between peers would imply a certain availability on a Friday night.

---

The updated context that the show is the Gilmore Girls doesn't really change anything. Lorelai is an adult and during the show is in relationships with a number of different people. The conversation seems like a two digs at her mother, firstly that she is capable of clothing her own child appropriately and secondly suggesting a reason why she might not be able to that simultaneously puts the fault onto her own mother whilst calling back to the underlying premise of the show, Lorelai's teen pregnancy that resulted in Rory.

The [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/GilmoreGirls) page praises wordplay as one of the selling points of the show.

> What really sets Gilmore Girls apart from other shows of its type is the heavy use of clever, fast-paced wordplay. Really fast.

Sexual innuendo is at heart wordplay, no matter what else it means for the characters.

Comment: There is utterly no connection to sexual innuendo.

Comment: Lorelai is not Rory’s sister, she is her mother.

Comment: I have no idea why the downvotes; this was my first interpretation. (Note, as mentioned in another comment, that Lorelai is a single woman in her 30s and Em is Lorelai's mother.)

Comment: @chrylis The downvotes are because this couldn't be further from sexual innuendo, this answer is completely incorrect and doesn't understand the context of the show at all.

Comment: @linksassin I fully admit I don't understand the context of the show. There was none given in the question at the time. In isolation I think the point stands.

Comment: I can see where you are coming from. That single line in isolation could be interpreted that way, however the preceding line is context enough to know that that that isn't the case here. The line is about refuting the need to be reminded of the number of days in the week, it has nothing to do with a sexual innuendo.

Comment: Perhaps sexual innuendo is the wrong phrasing, but it's extremely obvious that it means she doesn't bother with panties on Friday.  If that is sexual innuendo or not is, I suppose, subjective.

Comment: It doesn't even have to be so far as not wearing panties on Friday. Day-of-the-Week panties (actually, anything prints) are typically cheaper, simpler materials. She could just as likely be implying she wears racy undies on Fridays, which is a common date night.

Comment: It seems there are multiple possible interpretations of this line, then... +1

Answer (score 5):

Lorleia was poking at her mom for stating an obvious fact that there are five days in a school week.

> WLor: Really? Because my days-of-the-week underwear only go to
>   Thursday.

Sarcastically suggesting she thought there were only 4 days based on her set of available underwear.

> Emily: Is that a joke?
>
> Lor: Two skirts are fine, mom.

Satisfied that her Mom is thrown off guard, she confirms her assertion that the two skirts she bought will be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Days of the week underwear are usually for school-aged children and sold seven panties in a pack (with one day of the week printed on each panty).  Lorelai is sarcastically joking that she only thought there were four days in the school week because her days of the week underwear only **go** from Monday **to** Thursday. (In other words, she is pretending she didn't realize there are five school days because she only has Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday panties and no panties with "Friday" printed on them.)